# I can't connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I can't connect to SQL Server database engine for first time after installation.

I asked it once but marc_s closed that. Really it's my big problem .

Server name is empty. What should I type for this?

I use it in my personal laptop and I am not professional, it means I want use it just as a tables like access .

Someone help me please .

Comment: Hi, Arash. This is not a web site for those types of questions. This site is for programmers and technologists to show, discuss and solve programming questions. Sorry.

Comment: Aw come on... This is a fair question for a brand new programmer.  Be nice.  We all started somewhere.

Comment: Just to be clear: **I didn't close your previous question** - quite the contrary, I provided an answer as a comment. Did you try that??

Comment: so sorry mark ,,, i thought you closed that ,,, yeah i tried your answer but doesn't worked . you said i try "." or ".\SQLEXPRESS" but the solution is ".\MyInstance"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server name is the name of the machine that SQL Server is installed on.
if it's on the local machine, you can use a single period.  if it's on your machine, but you installed it with an Instance name of "MyInstance" you can use ".\MyInstance".

As a side note, the original question was probably closed because there wasn't enough info in the question to answer completely. In order for us to help you , we would need to know the machine name that this was installed on, what options you selected through the installation wizard, etc.  The best we can do is guess, and that makes the question, technically, unanswerable.

It could also be because this is such a newbie question - sometimes we forget that we all started somewhere.

I'd suggest you start here for your learning experience:  http://www.asp.net/sql-server/videos

Particularly videos #8 and #9 - these should answer your question.

Comment: oh my god david u r my Savior . thanks a lot .

Comment: for others maybe read this and have same problem : use .\MyInstance except ./MyInstance

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local instance for the server name try (local)

Comment: thank you but local doesn't worked . i used ./MyInstance and it's worked .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a period `.` for the server name

You need to be in the administrators group (done during the installation), or if you have the SA password (also set during installation)

Comment: thank you but . doesn't worked . i used ./MyInstance and it's worked .